# Get Tags by Video ID

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I'm trying to pull tag info from videos using the Vimeo Advanced API to display on a portfolio-style page. I cannot seem to find a method that simply pulls that information-- it seems like vimeo.videos.getByTag is the closest, but I don't want to request the videos by tag, only display them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced/methods/vimeo.videos.getInfo/

Comment: getInfo doesn't dump tags

Comment: It did for me when I tried it with a random video in the “playground” they offer.

Answer (score 0):

Use https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced/methods/vimeo.videos.getInfo/ to get general info about a given video – it includes the tags the video is tagged with.